# Why is this ideal projective but not free?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, modules, projective-module

> Let $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ and $I=(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$. How can I prove that $I$ is projective but not free?

Comment: If it were free, it would have to be principal, right? What is its norm?

Comment: Compute the fractional ideal that is its inverse. Using the ideal product then allows you to write it as a split summand of a free module of rank two. This implies that it is projective.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please see $\S 3.5.4$ -- "Projective verus free" -- in my [commutative algebra notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/integral.pdf).  In particular, Proposition 27 and the exercise follow it step you through showing that the ideal $\langle 3, 1+ \sqrt{-5} \rangle$ is projective but not free.

The same techniques apply to $I = \langle 2, 1+ \sqrt{-5} \rangle$.  (In fact, I view it as a happy accident that your question is similar but not identical to what is treated in my notes.  You'll learn more by figuring out what slight modifications you need to make.)

As I say in the notes, much of the presentation owes a debt to [this blurb](http://www.math.uconn.edu/%7Ekconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/splittingmodules.pdf) of Keith Conrad.

$\newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow}$
$\newcommand{\Ker}{\operatorname{Ker}}$
$\newcommand{\pp}{\mathfrak{p}}$
$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$

**Added**: Here is the relevant portion from the notes.

> Proposition: Let $I$ and $J$ be comaximal ideals in a domain $R$, and consider the $R$-module
> map $q: I \oplus J \ra R$ given by $(x,y) \mapsto x+y$.  Then:
> a) The map $q$ is surjective.
> b) $\Ker(q) = \{(x,-x) \ | \ x \in I \cap J\}$, hence is isomorphic as an $R$-module to $I \cap J$.
> c) We have an isomorphism of $R$-modules
> $I \oplus J \cong IJ \oplus R$.
> d) Thus if $IJ$ is a principal ideal, $I$ and $J$ are projective modules.

It is clear that for any ideals $I$ and $J$, the image of the map $q$ is
the ideal $I+J$, and we are assuming $I+J = R$, whence part a).
Part b) is essentially immediate: details are left to the reader.
Combining parts a) and b) we get a short exact sequence $0 \ra I \cap J \ra I \oplus J \ra R \ra 0$.
But $R$ is free, hence projective, and thus the sequence splits,
giving part c).  Finally, a nonzero principal ideal $(x)$ in a domain $R$ is isomorphic as an $R$-module to $R$ itself: indeed, multiplication by $x$
gives the isomorphism $R \ra (x)$.  So if $IJ$ is principal, $I\oplus J \cong R^2$ and $I$ and $J$ are both direct summands of a free module.

In particular, if we can find in a domain $R$ two comaximal nonprincipal
ideals $I$ and $J$ with $IJ$ principal, then $I$ and $J$ are finitely generated projective nonfree $R$-modules.  The following exercise asks you to work through an explicit example.

Exercise 3.30: Let $R = \Z[\sqrt{-5}]$, and put

$\pp_1 = \langle 3, 1+ \sqrt{-5} \rangle, \ \pp_2 = \langle 3, 1 - \sqrt{-5} \rangle.$
a) Show that $R/\pp_1 \cong R/\pp_2 \cong \Z/3\Z$, so $\pp_1$ and $\pp_2$
are maximal ideals of $R$.
b) Show that $\pp_1 + \pp_2 = R$ (or equivalently, that $\pp_1 \neq \pp_2$).
c) Show that $\pp_1 \pp_2 = (3)$.
d) Show that neither $\pp_1$ nor $\pp_2$ is principal.   (Suggestion: show
that if $\pp_1 = (x+\sqrt{-5}y)$ then $\pp_2 = (x-\sqrt{-5}y)$ and thus
there are integers $x,y$ such that $x^2+5y^2 = \pm 3$.)
e) Conclude that $\pp_1$ and $\pp_2$ are (in fact isomorphic) nonfree
finitely generated projective modules over the domain $R$.
f) Show that $\pp^2$ is principal, and thus that the class of $\pp$ in
$\widetilde{K_0(R)}$ is $2$-torsion.

This construction looks very specific, and the number-theoretically inclined
reader is warmly invited to play around with other quadratic rings and more
general rings of integers of number fields to try to figure out what is really
going on.  From our perspective, we will (much later on) gain a deeper
understanding of this in terms of the concepts of invertible ideals, the Picard group and Dedekind domains.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews and Pete: Please don't use the comment section to engage in extended **meta** discussions. I am purging the comments in a couple minutes. If you wish I (or another mod) can copy all the comments to a Meta post and you can continue your discussion there. Please flag if you would like that done.

Comment: Could you hint me as to how should i find that second ideal for the case of $(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$? I know that $(2,1-\sqrt{-5}) = (2,1+\sqrt{-5})$. So I can't use that one, and I don't find it quite trivial